# Parent child relationship hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I've been trying to recreate the parent/child scenario with hibernate, I used this as an example (very new to hibernate):

http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/

My situation is similar to this. I am working on a project that has some task objects which should be part of some task flow object.

- So there are two entities task and taskflow.
- Taskflow should have many or at least one task.
- There are already some tasks in the task table, now I want to insert some entries into taskflow table so that taskflow object has list or set of tasks.

**Forgot to mention in my original question :**

- Task can be inside many different task flows

My taskflow looks something like :

```
class Taskflow{
   int taskflowid;
   String taskflowname;
   List<Task> tasklist;
}
```

in the database taskflow has 2 fields `taskflowid` and `taskflowname`.

This is how Task looks like :

```
class Task{
 //many properties/fields
}
```

Taking this example into consideration when compared to examples I googled, there is always some kind of relation from Task back to the TaskFlow. Is that necessary? I just want taskflow to have reference to task. Am I thinking this one all wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't declare relationship it would be simple member variables. In order to hibernate understand that you have one to many relationship you need to specify it in some for `.hbm` , `annotation`

```
@OneToMany //This for hibernate to understand that you have one to many relationship with Task
List<Task> tasklist;
```

inside Task

```
@ManyToOne
Taskflow taskFlow
```

Remember default names will be used to generate column names. Please refer tutorial over [here](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-one-to-many-using-annotations-1.html)

Comment: do I need a field in the taskflow table for that?

Comment: Field will be required at the other end. ie `@ManyToOne` inside `Task` which will create a mapping between `Task and `Taskflow`

Comment: so you suggest that I add field to task which will specify to which taksflow that task belongs to? In my case task can be inside many different task flows, I forgot to mention that one in my question I see it now.

Answer (score -1):

Hibernate supports relationships of different cardinality (one-to-one, one-to-many/many-to-one, many-to-many) and different directionality (unidirectional or bidirectional).

In your case you have a many-to-many relationship, which can be either unidirectional (if `Task` don't need to contain a collection of all `TaskFlow`s it's a part of), or bidirectional.

For example, a unidirectional relatioship from `TaskFlow` to `Task`:

```
class Taskflow {
    ...
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Task> tasks;
    ...
}
```

**See also:**

- [Chapter 7. Collection mapping](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html)

Comment: sorry forgot to add some more details, can you see the question update. What would you do in that case?